# Minimum and Maximum values --Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Trying to get this output:

Trying to get this output in Oracle 8i:

```
column1 |time
________|_______
  ABC   | 00:00:01
  END   | 01:00:03
  123   | 00:00:04
  END   | 01:00:07
  ABC   | 00:00:08
  END   | 01:00:09
  ABC   | 00:00:10
  END   | 01:00:10
```

with this output from another query

```
   column1  |starttime  |endtime     | ID
    ________|___________|___________ |
      ABC   | 00:00:01  |  01:00:01  | 1
      ABC   | 00:00:02  |  01:00:02  | 1
      ABC   | 00:00:03  |  01:00:03  | 1
      123   | 00:00:04  |  01:00:04  | 2
      123   | 00:00:05  |  01:00:05  | 2
      123   | 00:00:06  |  01:00:06  | 2
      123   | 00:00:07  |  01:00:07  | 2
      ABC   | 00:00:08  |  01:00:08  | 3
      ABC   | 00:00:09  |  01:00:09  | 3
      ABC   | 00:00:10  |  01:00:10  | 4
```

This query gets min and max for only starttime column:

```
SELECT (
  CASE
    WHEN n.n = 1
    THEN column1
    ELSE 'END'
  END) AS column1,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN n.n = 1
    THEN firsttime
    ELSE lasttime
  END) AS "time"
FROM
  (SELECT column1,
    id,
    MIN(starttime) AS firsttime,
    MAX(starttime) AS lasttime
  FROM t
  GROUP BY column1,
    id
  ) t
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT 1 AS n FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 FROM dual
  ) n
ORDER BY id,
  column1,
  n.n;
```

Now that I have another column called `endtime`, I wonder how can I consider this column as well and get the `END` values from this column instead? I'm struggling because of `n.n` is `1` when I have only one record for `ID`.

Comment: Considering end time always greater than start time.. `MAX(endtime)` is itself enough?

Comment: @downvoter: Could I know why?

Comment: @OracleUser: Problem is when I have only 1 row per ID. In this case n.n will be 1 anyway I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using below query,

```
with  DUMMYDATA AS
(    
SELECT 'ABC' COL1,  '00:00:01' STARTTIME, '01:00:01' ENDTIME, '1' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'ABC' COL1,  '00:00:02' STARTTIME, '01:00:02' ENDTIME, '1' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'ABC' COL1,  '00:00:03' STARTTIME, '01:00:03' ENDTIME, '1' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '123' COL1,  '00:00:04' STARTTIME, '01:00:04' ENDTIME, '2' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '123' COL1,  '00:00:05' STARTTIME, '01:00:05' ENDTIME, '2' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '123' COL1,  '00:00:06' STARTTIME, '01:00:06' ENDTIME, '2' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT '123' COL1,  '00:00:07' STARTTIME, '01:00:07' ENDTIME, '2' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'ABC' COL1,  '00:00:08' STARTTIME, '01:00:08' ENDTIME, '3' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'ABC' COL1,  '00:00:09' STARTTIME, '01:00:09' ENDTIME, '3' ID FROM DUAL
UNION
SELECT 'ABC' COL1,  '00:00:10' STARTTIME, '01:00:10' ENDTIME, '4' ID FROM DUAL
) 
SELECT  * FROM
(
    SELECT COL1, MIN(STARTTIME) TIMEDATA, ID FROM DUMMYDATA 
    GROUP BY COL1, ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'END', MAX(ENDTIME) TIMEDATA,ID FROM DUMMYDATA
    GROUP BY COL1, ID
)
ORDER BY ID, TIMEDATA
```